# How would I set the alignment of cells in a pivot table created with EPPlus?

Tags: excel, vb.net, epplus

**At this time, this functionality has not been added to EPPlus. EPPlus is reviewing the addition of horizonal alignment to pivot table styles as a possible addition to future versions.**

I have added a simple pivot table to an Excel Worksheet in Excel with EPPlus from a VB.NET application.

- The pivot table is created by the code below and the results are numerically correct.
- I would like to set the alignment of the cells in the body of the pivot table.

The code that I am using to create the pivot table is below.

```
   Private Sub AddPivotTable()

        ' Add a worksheet for the pivot table, get a cell range that contains the data to summarize.
        xlPivotsheet = xlPackage.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("Summary")

        Dim dataRange = xlWorksheet.Cells("A1:" + xlWorksheet.Dimension.End.Address)

        ' Create the Pivot Table on the "Summary" Worksheet.
        Dim pivotTable = xlPivotsheet.PivotTables.Add(xlPivotsheet.Cells("B4"),
                                                      dataRange,
                                                      "pivotTable")

        ' Set pivot table properties.
        pivotTable.MultipleFieldFilters = True
        pivotTable.RowGrandTotals = True
        pivotTable.ColumGrandTotals = False
        pivotTable.Compact = True
        pivotTable.CompactData = True
        pivotTable.DataOnRows = False
        pivotTable.GridDropZones = False
        pivotTable.Outline = False
        pivotTable.OutlineData = False
        pivotTable.ShowError = True
        pivotTable.ErrorCaption = "[error]"
        pivotTable.ShowHeaders = True
        pivotTable.UseAutoFormatting = True
        pivotTable.ApplyWidthHeightFormats = True
        pivotTable.ShowDrill = True
        pivotTable.FirstDataCol = 3
        pivotTable.RowHeaderCaption = "Provider"

        ' Set the Row Fields.
        Dim providerField = pivotTable.Fields("Provider")
        providerField.Sort = Table.PivotTable.eSortType.Ascending
        pivotTable.RowFields.Add(providerField)

        Dim serviceField = pivotTable.Fields("ServiceCode")
        pivotTable.RowFields.Add(serviceField)

        ' Set the Column Fields.
        Dim monthField = pivotTable.Fields("Month")
        monthField.Sort = Table.PivotTable.eSortType.Ascending
        pivotTable.ColumnFields.Add(monthField)

        ' Set the Count Fields.
        Dim countField = pivotTable.Fields("Provider")

       ' Format(?)
        xlPackage.Save()

        xlPivotsheet.Columns(2).AutoFit()

        If xlPivotsheet.Dimension IsNot Nothing Then

            Dim pivotColumns = xlPivotsheet.Dimension.Columns

            For col As Integer = 2 To 1 + pivotColumns
                xlPivotsheet.Columns(col).Width = 10
                xlPivotsheet.Columns(col).Style.HorizontalAlignment = Style.ExcelHorizontalAlignment.Center
            Next

        End If


End Sub
```

- The workbook is saved following the call to `AddPivotTable()` via `xlPackage.Save`.

**Questions and What I have tried...**

1. The pivot table results are not created until the user Enables the workbook for editing. (Email recipients will notice that no pivot table appears when they do a preview in Outlook). Is there a EPPlus function that aggregates and writes the pivot table?
2. I tried the `xlPivotSheet.Cells...` call at the bottom of the `AddPivotTable` procedure with the known coordinates of the pivot table for the test data. This has no effect on the horizontal alignment.
3. `xlPackage.Save()` is called after the call to `AddPivotTable()`.
4. I also tried setting the alignment of the columns. This had no effect on the cell alignment of the columns. An example is below:

```
xlPivotsheet.Column(5).Style.HorizontalAlignment = Style.ExcelHorizontalAlignment.Center
```

5. Does anyone have an example of programmatically setting the alignment of cells in a pivot table?
6. I looked at the `pivotTable.Fields.Styles` but found no way to set the alignment of the `ExcelPivotTableAreaStyle` object returned by `AddAllData()`.
7. Is there any way call to have the pivot table calculated and written to the worksheet so that the Worksheet `Dimensions` object is not nothing? I tried doing a `xlPackage.Save()`, but `Dimensions` is still null (or Nothing). This may require me to save, close, and re-open the package. `Calculate` had no effect and I do not see a refresh.

- Note: `Dimension` does not apply to a worksheet that only contains a pivot table.

9. Neither of the methods below affect the horizontal alignment.

- The first method tries to apply a center alignment to the cells in the data area of the pivot table.

```
            ' Create a range object to center-align the cells.
            Dim topLeftRow As Integer = 5
            Dim topLeftCol As Integer = 3
            Dim bottomRightRow As Integer = 5 + distinctProviders + mainTable.Rows.Count
            Dim bottomRightCol As Integer = 3 + distinctMonths

            Dim pivotRange As ExcelRange = xlPivotsheet.Cells(topLeftRow, topLeftCol, bottomRightRow, bottomRightCol)

            With pivotRange.Style
                .HorizontalAlignment = ExcelHorizontalAlignment.Center
            End With
```

- The second method used the `AddAllData()` to obtain
  the`ExcelPivotTableAreaStyle` object for data area. There are no alignment properties in `ExcelPivotTableAreaStyle` returned by `AddAllData()`.